# How do I push my Ruby application live on cPanel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cpanel, web-hosting, whm

After almost a hundred support emails with level 1, 2, and 3 technical analysts with cPanel I have not been able to push my Ruby website live. I have a basic website that is live on GitHub and Heroku but does not want to work on GoDaddy servers with cPanel. How do I set up my ruby app for the server?

In other words, the support analyst said I need to initialize my app way more in order for it to work but my expertise is pretty much limited to front-end development.

I am completely stuck and desperate.

If anyone could list out the basic steps that would be fantastic.

Comment: Does your host have Ruby/Rails installed?

Comment: Do you have complete control of the machine?

Comment: GoDaddy's hosting is really not the ideal place to deploy a Rails application, but if you want to try, use [Capistrano](https://capistranorb.com) as a deployment automation tool. cPanel, as far as I know, can't handle it.

Comment: cpanel can be used to manage rails apps if the host has ruby/rails configured and cpanel is working/configured properly.

Comment: Maybe have a look here https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/74Docs/Ruby+on+Rails

Comment: Also, why bother with cPanel which appears to have discontinued support for Rails? There are many better alternatives, but for deployments you're very likely gonna need some basic linux knowledge at least.